# How do I check if there is a uppercase letter in a string within a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of words:

```
str_list = [“There”, “is”, “ a Red”, “”, “shirt, but not a white One”]
```

I want to check if there is a capital letter in every word in the list
and if so I want to make a new list like this:

```
split_str_list = [“There”, “is”, “ a ”, ”Red”, “”, “shirt, but a white “, ”One”]
```

I tried:

```
for word in range(len(str_list)):
if word.isupper():
    print str_list[word]
```

but it does not checking each letter but all of them in a string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.split()`:

```
import re
import itertools
str_list = ['There', 'is', ' a Red', '', 'shirt, but not a white One']
final_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([re.split('\s(?=[A-Z])', i) for i in str_list]))
```

Output:

```
['There', 'is', ' a', 'Red', '', 'shirt, but not a white', 'One']
```

Comment: The whitespace should be part of the lookahead or removed to correspond to output requested in the question

Comment: @sapht no, because then it will try to split on a space, proceeded by a space and a capital letter. The longest empty string in any of elements is one empty string.

Comment: it is to comlex for me

Comment: also tried for word in str_list:
    while str_list[j]isupper():
        split_str_list = str_list.split(j)
    print split_str_list

Comment: @Ajax1234 Right, need lookbehind, but it turns out re.split doesn't support splitting on empty match. Author wants to split `' a Red'` into `' a ', 'Red'`, i.e. 0-width match followed by capital letter preceeded by space. It's "coming soon" according to 3.5 docs. So not possible with re.split without placeholders or whitespace replacement.