# Difficulties with homework about strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list, letter

I am having a trouble with homework in Python class.

A list of strings is given with the name str_list. Write a code that will create a new list of strings with the name split_str_list which is splitted whenever a capital letter appears. It will be done by the following rules:

1. Don't split a list without a capital letter
2. Don't split first or last characters.
3. In any other case you should split the list in the index which the capital letter appears at. The capital letter will be assigned to the next string (see eg)

Former questions have regarded a capital letter in the beginning of words but I need to know when and how to split them even when they are at the middle of the word.

e.g for:

```
str_list = [“This”, “is”, “not a Red”, “”, “wine, but a white One”]
```

I should get:

```
split_str_list = [“This”, “is”, “not a ”, ”Red”, “”, “wine, but a white “, ”One”]
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What went wrong?

Comment: How come this question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077275/how-do-i-check-if-there-is-a-uppercase-letter-in-a-string-within-a-list-of-strin/47077345#47077345) one, which has been asked today itself? Also the example is almost same.

Comment: I tried a nsted "while" loop which where I create a new list of of characters for each word and when I hit the end of the word or a capital letter I join all the characters in the new list into a word and assign that word into split_str_list. it Didn't work well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i check if there is a uppercase letter in a string within a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077275/how-do-i-check-if-there-is-a-uppercase-letter-in-a-string-within-a-list-of-strin)

Comment: Its not because as much as the examples are similar that code doesnt help me because it does not split capital letters when they are not the first letter of the word. I need to know how to split them whenever, not just as a first character of a word. thanks.